# The name of a cycle with chords added to one of its vertices

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Consider a cycle $C$ and its vertex $v$. If $C$ has $n$ vertices, then we can add at most $n-3$ chords to $v$. In the case of $n-3$ chords, the obtained graph is called *shell* and denoted as $C(n,n-3)$. What is the name of the graph if we add $k\leq n-3$ chords, i.e. $C(n,k)$? I want to publish some results on these graphs and going to call them *pre-shells*, but don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This graph is the [fan graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FanGraph.html) $F_{1,n-1}$, where a vertex $v$ is joined to all vertices of an $(n-1)$-vertex path. (The fan graph notation is more general; $F_{k,n}$ involves taking an independent set of order $k$ and a path of order $n$, and adding all edges between them.)

There are other names for special cases: the graph you call $C(5,2)$ is also called the [gem graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GemGraph.html), for example.

There is no notation (that I am aware of) for the graphs you are considering calling "pre-shells". Part of that is that your definition of these graphs is not well-defined: there are multiple non-isomorphic graphs that are obtained from a cycle $C_n$ by adding $k$ chords out of the same vertex. So referring to a graph as $C(n,k)$ for $0<k<n-3$ would be ambiguous.

You can, of course, refer to the class of all graphs of this type. Conventionally, I would expect notation like $\mathcal C(n,k)$ or $\mathcal C_{n,k}$ (with the letter C as fancy as you can make it) to refer to a class of graphs, and an ordinary $C$ to refer to a single graph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, the wheel $W_{n-1}$ is not isomorphic to $C(n,n-3)$. Say, $W_4$ contains $4$ $3$-cycles, while $C(5,2)$ has $3$ $3$-cycles. Also, I found this strange notation here: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.403.6553&rep=rep1&type=pdf I don't think we shall say this is something ambiguous since the class of graphs is meant (like cycles, trees, wheels).

Comment: P.S. Probably, the definition I gave is a bit confusing. I mean $v$ belongs to $C$.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up and the fan is in fact not isomorphic to the wheel. Your graph still *is* the fan graph, but it is not the wheel graph. I will edit.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. Actually, I didn't hear the names *fan* and *gem* before.